# Sub match in javascrtip/apps script get's "null" result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hi i have mails in Gmail that will be replied to with different answer-templates depending on keywords in the subject.

In this example i have 5 emails that's being scanned, and if they have the word "Prodcution" in the subject it should logg "Sucess!", there is only 1 mail that contains the word Production, but the logger writes out "Sucess!" five times, I just want it to write it out 1 time for the mail that actually contains the word "Production". What am i doing wrong?

```
function msmama() {

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

        var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];  
    var sub = message.getSubject();

        var res = sub.match(/Production/g);
    if (res = "Production"){

      Logger.log("Sucess!");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if (res = "Production"){
```

with

```
if (res === "Production"){
```

Also `match` returns an array or null if there are no results, so a better approach would be:

```
if (res)
```

Comment: Thanks actually if (res == "Production"){ worked for me